# Paging when there is no order column value?

Tags: mysql, paging

I have a table as follows (created in MySQL 5):

**Article**: `Id | View-Count | Title`

Suppose Id is auto-increase, View-Count is a long indicating the number of views

If I select all articles sort by Id, then it is easy to do paging something like:

```
Select * from Article Where id < lastViewedArticleId Order By Id DESC Limit pageSize
```

However, if I sort by View-Count I couldn't do like the above query since surely there are some articles having the same view-counts, then I would miss some of them. Currently, I have to do like this: (which is a bad solution if there are millions of records)

```
Select * from Article Order By View-Count DESC Limit start, pageSize
```

Does anyone have some solutions for this case?

Comment: If they can be of the same value - you need to introduce additional sorting criteria for sorting to be consistent. It might be `id DESC`. That way you're not in stuck anymore

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence table for the article and update the sequence periodically (cron). Then paginate that one and use it to break things apart.

```
SELECT @sequence := 0;
```

`CREATE TABLE Article_sequence Select @sequence := sequence +1 as sequence, article_id from Article Order By View-Count DESC`

Then do your pagination from that.

Cron job it every hour. That way you won't miss a beat.